# Can std::stoi verify if the value of digit exceeds range of base?

Tags: c++, std

I'm using std::stoi in following manner

```
int ConvertToInt( const std::string& aVal )
{
    int lVal = std::stoi( aVal, nullptr, 0 );
    return lVal;
}
```

Third argument in std::stoi was provided as **0** to convert automatically both DEC and HEX values.
I also use try-catch structure to catch *std::invalid_argument*, *std::out_of_range* and *( ... )* althought when I provide number as **0xgg** no exception is thrown and the number is converted to **0** which is not my intention.
Is it possbile to catch digits, which are out of range and throw some exception ?

Comment: you need to pass in a pointer in the second parameter and check that all characters in your string have been consumed

Comment: Extending on @AlanBirtles : `size_t n; stoi(aVal, &n, 0);` – as you want to consume the whole string `n` should be equal to the string's length, of course – or, if you want to accept such input, you continue iterating after `n` characters to check if all further ones are white-space only...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::stoi` parses the string until an invalid character is encountered, which is interpreted to be the end of the integer.

> Is it possbile to catch digits, which are out of range and throw some exception ?

Yes. You can use the `pos` argument. After the conversion, the pointed integer will contain the index of the first unconverted character. If the `*pos` is not equal to the size of the input, then there are unconverted characters, which must have not been valid. You can throw an exception in such case.